# Php search filter. Array returns NULL

Tags: php, laravel

This is Search Controller

```php
if ($request->has('query')) {
    $search = $request->get('query');
    $search = addslashes(str_replace('"', '', json_encode($search)));

    $solution = Service::all();
    $solutions = array();

    foreach ($solution as $id => $val) {
        if (strpos(mb_strtolower($val['title']), mb_strtolower($search))) {
            $solutions[] = $solution[$id];
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection containing 10 \App\Models\Service models]
When I run the `dd` command, 10 pieces of data appear.
For example when I search for 'customer' the array returns null even though this data is exist.

This is search.blade.php

```html
<div class="header-search-form default-search">
    <form action="{{ route('search') }}" method="GET" class="search-form-top">
        <input class="search-field" type="text" name="query" id="query" value="{{ request()->input('query') }}" placeholder="{{ trans('general.search') }}">
        <button class="search-submit">
            <i class="search-btn-icon fa fa-search"></i>
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

This is search-result.blade.php

```html
<div class="row row--35">
    @foreach ($solutions as $solution)
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mt-10" >
            <a href="{{route('service_detail',$solution->slug)}}" class="box-large-image__wrap wow move-up">
                <div class="box-large-image__box">
                    <div class="box-large-image__midea">
                        <div class="images-midea">
                            <img src="{{ coverImg('service',$solution->id) }}" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                            <div class="button-wrapper">
                                <div class="btn tm-button">
                                     <span class="button-text">Detayları Gör</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="heading-wrap">
                                <h5 class="heading">{{ $solution->title }}</h5>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box-large-image__content mt-30 text-center"></div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: How are you returning your data from your controller?

Comment: `$solution` is an array of `Service`, `$solutions` is the exact same array, but filtered and just the IDs. Not to mentioned, you then use `$solution` in the foreach loop in the view! Those names are confusing. Couldn't this be (this is shorter cause comment space) `$solutions = Service::where('title', $search)->pluck('id')`?

Comment: Yes you're right but there are some turkish characters. I store the data in json format as it has dual language support. I have to use that. This doesn't work quite right either. 
For Example: {"tr":"Elektronik Belge Y\u00f6netim Sistemi","en":"Corpoate Platform"}

Comment: To do the same as `strpos(mb_strtolower($val['title']), mb_strtolower($search))`, you set the database connection charset to the appropriate charset (e.g. utf8) and `Service::where('LOWER(title)', mb_strtolower($search))`

Comment: In addition to what @MHewison said: Could you please post the code of the whole controller or at least the whole method's code?